# Count non-empty lists in a lists of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to count the number of non-empty lists in a list of lists with recursive code.
My goal is to write something simple like:

```
prod :: Num a => [a] -> a
prod [] = 1
prod (x:xs) = x * prod xs
```

I already have the deifniton and an idea for the edge condition:

```
nonEmptyCount :: [[a]] -> Int
nonEmptyCount [[]] = 0
```

I have no idea how to continue, any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your base case, can be simplified. As a base-case, we can take the empty list `[]`, not a singleton list with an empty list. For the recursive case, we can consider `(x:xs)`. Here we will need to make a distinction between `x` being an empty list, and `x` being a non-empty list. We can do that with pattern matching, or with guards:

```
nonEmptyCount :: [[a]] -> Int
nonEmptyCount [] = 0
nonEmptyCount (x:xs) = -- …
```

That being said, you do not need recursion at all. You can first *filter* your list, to omit empty lists, and then call length on that list:

```
nonEmptyCount :: [[a]] -> Int
nonEmptyCount = length . filter (…)
```

here you still need to fill in `…`.

Answer (score 2):

Old fashion pattern matching should be:

```
import Data.List

nonEmptyCount :: [[a]] -> Int
nonEmptyCount []     = 0
nonEmptyCount (x:xs) = if null x then 1 + (nonEmptyCount xs) else nonEmptyCount xs
```

Comment: or, more *value-oriented*, `nonEmptyCount (x:xs) = (if null x then 1 else 0) + nonEmptyCount xs`. less "how", more "what". :)

Comment: @WillNess, or even `nonEmptyCount (x:xs) = fromEnum (null x) + nonEmptyCount xs`.

Comment: @dfeuer like in C, huh. `fromEnum` here can feel a bit opaque though, needs a bit getting used to. (?) another, more visually apparent possibility: `bool 0 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The following was posted in a comment, now deleted:

```
countNE = sum<$>(1<$)<<<(>>=(1`take`))
```

This most certainly will look intimidating to the non-initiated, but actually, it is equivalent to

```
        = sum <$> (1 <$) <<< (>>= (1 `take`))
        = sum <$> (1 <$) . (take 1 =<<)
        = sum . fmap (const 1) . concatMap (take 1)
        = sum . map (const 1) . concat . map (take 1)
```

which is further equivalent to

```
countNE xs  =  sum . map (const 1) . concat $ map (take 1) xs
            =  sum . map (const 1) $ concat [take 1 x | x <- xs]
            =  sum . map (const 1) $ [ r | x <- xs, r <- take 1 x]
            =  sum $ [const 1 r | (y:t) <- xs, r <- take 1 (y:t)]   -- sneakiness!
            =  sum   [const 1 r | (y:_) <- xs, r <- [y]]
            =  sum   [const 1 y | (y:_) <- xs]
            =  sum   [ 1        | (_:_) <- xs]    -- replace each
                         --   non-empty list
                         --             in 
                         --                xs
               -- with 1, and
           --  sum all the 1s up!
            =  (length . (take 1 =<<)) xs
            =  (length . filter (not . null)) xs
```

which should be much clearer, even if in a bit sneaky way. It isn't recursive in itself, yes, but both `sum` and the [list-comprehension](/questions/tagged/list-comprehension) would be implemented recursively by a given Haskell implementation.

This reimplements `length` as `sum . (1 <$)`, and `filter p xs` as `[x | x <- xs, p x]`, and uses the equivalence `not (null xs) === (length xs) >= 1`.

See? Haskell is fun. Even if it doesn't yet feel like it, but it will be. :)